# Visual Studios NuGet Manager Packages not Adding File Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, specflow

I am attempting to install some Testing Packages for a project, namely Selenium and Specflow through Visual Studio 2017's NuGet Manager.

Screenshot of NuGet Manager View
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGi8.png]

However, despite the packages installing successfully, when I made a "Tests" project in my solution, with the packages installed onto that project, and clicked Add File, there was no templates for the Specflow files or Selenium files.

I tried looking in the Extensions Manager, but they are not in there to enable or disable, and multiple attempts to redownload have produced the same result.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the specflow extension in visual studio?

If not, go to: Tools => Extensions and updates => Online (left hand menu) => search SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2017. Then restart visual studio, the installer will start. Install the extension and then start visual studio. You should now be able to add feature files.